# C#: Is there an analog of IList for HashSets?

Tags: c#, list, hashset

When I work with a List of an unknown type, I can use the IList interface like this:

```
public void DoSomething(object o)
{
  if (o is IList oAsList)
  {
    foreach (object listItem in oAsList)
      Console.WriteLine(listItem.ToString());

    oAsList.Clear();

    Type typeOfList = oAsList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    oAsList.Add(GetRandomInstanceOfType<typeOfList>());
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work for HashSets, as there is nothing like IHashSet. I could cast it to IEnumerable, but then I am missing methods like .Clear() and .Add() which I need, because I want to copy the elements from one HashSet of any type to another HashSet of that type.

How can I do this with HashSets?

Comment: You may use [`ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1?view=netframework-4.8) or even [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: complete list of interfaces implemented by `HashSet` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1

Comment: I guess you could always use reflection to call `Clear`, after checking it's a `HashSet` using `GetType`. Would that solution satisfy you? Or do you want something cleaner?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I believe they are looking for a non-generic interface to use.

Comment: Why do you have a method that takes `object` in the first place?  Why not something like `public void DoSomething<T>(ICollection<T> o)` instead?  That way you protect against someone passing an `int` or a `string` to this method.  Also you cannot use `typeOfList` as a generic type in your code but if you make the method generic you can do `GetRandomInstanceOfType<T>`

Comment: @juharr Because the method SHOULD take objects, I just deal differently with valuetypes, classes and Lists of objects. But to do so, I need to identify them. If it's just values or non-list objects, I can copy the new value to the original value. For lists, I want to clear the original list and add the items of the updated list to the original list

Comment: @Aaginor That sounds like you should be using overloads.  Let the type system determine what you're dealing with instead of relying on reflection.

Comment: @juharr Might you explain a bit more detailed what you suggest? I know overloads, but I don't see how to use then in this situation, as I cannot overload a HashSet<T>. I guess I'll try to go with the suggestion of Sweeper and use reflection to get the clear and add method for the HashSet<T>. Thanks to all of you for the suggestions!